# Google BigQuery Scheduling Query error on Manual Run

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

I can successfully run Bigquery Scheduled Queries with @Run_time, @run_date parameters.

You can review Google's inadequate documentation on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries

But when I try, manual run fails; "Error in starting transfer runs: Request contains an invalid argument. Dismiss" not any detail :(

**Example code: (please be attentions i use @run_date)**

Destination table: test_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}
The parameter named table serves to create a different table for each day. 
For example

test_20181112

test_20181113 etc.

```
SELECT 
  @run_date AS mydate,
  title,
  author,
  text
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`
LIMIT
  10
```

**I think the problem is caused by the @run_date parameter in the query during manual operation.**

My project is a little more complicated, I've added this code so everyone can try it easily.
 
As I mentioned above, this scheduled task works correctly in the initial setup. But when I try to run manual, it gives an error.
Can you show me the way?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a bug in manunal run.

You should choose carefully the start date and the end date ( the same as a previous run ) in order to not get this error

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I found the cause of the problem;
If you select the end date today, it gives an error.
But if you choose the previous days, it doesn't give any error ..

Comment: I tried manual run to backfill October 2018 data, but got error `Error in starting transfer runs: Request contains an invalid argument`.

Comment: Can you explain of "the same as a previous run"? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Just to give you update. In my case, I got that error for manual run the scheduled query that contains udf javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add something here, since this is a "gotcha" in the BigQuery UI: using today's date as the end date in a scheduled query run will cause an issue, but setting it to one day ahead (i.e. tomorrow) should allow you to create a request with @run_date set to today.